# Need to Validate a couple of fields using code.in functions.php

Tags: regex, validation, woocommerce, registration

My first post here! I am setting up a woocommerce registration (the one which appears on the checkout page). I am using a plugin by Extendons: WooCommerce Custom Registration Fields Plugin which has everything but unfortunately I can't set the vaildation of some fields. Basically I have fields for registration numbers for doctors and nurse. The Doctor number needs to be validated (by regex probably) only if it is exactly 7 numbers (any numbers). The Nurses have this exact format: 00(Letter)0000(letter): o = any letter. The different registration number fields appear conditionally on whether Doctor or Nurse is selected. The plugin achieves all this no problem though.

I would be graeful if anyone could provide some insight or at least point me in the right direction as my php knowledge is limited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match only numbers that are 7 digits long, just add a trailing anchor using $, like this:

```
^(\d{7})$
```

That will match any number that is exactly 7 digits long.

**On PHP**

```
<?php

$re = "/^(\d{7})$/";
$test_input_doctor = "1234567"; // valid scenario
//$test_input_doctor = "12345678"; //invalid scenario, you can test it as well by just commenting out this line

if (preg_match($re, $test_input_doctor))
{
    echo "valid doctor id";
}
else
{
    echo "invalid doctor id";
}
?>
```